# PHP UTF-8 search not working

Tags: php, database, search, utf-8

For whatever weird reason I can't search non-English characters. The script dies. It dies at search, I think. Blank page, half of layout, nothing after PHP script.

Code was copied from a working site (my own), minus layout, so it *should* work. But it doesn't.

On search.php:

```
<meta charset='utf-8' />
```

On form:

```
<form action='search.php' method='get' accept-charset='utf-8'>
```

On db_connect.php:

```
mysqli_set_charset($db_connect, "utf8");
```

On database:
utf8_general_ci

What else am I missing?

search.php (results page):

```
<?php

include ("php/form.php");

$searchTerm = trim ($_GET['keyname']);

if (!empty ($searchTerm)) {
    if (strlen ($searchTerm) > 2) {
        include "php/search.php";
        } else {
            echo "<h1>Enter 3 or More Characters</h1><hr />$search_form";
            };
    } else {
        echo "<h1>Enter Search Term</h1><hr />$search_form>";
        };

?>
```

php/search.php:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE first_name LIKE '%$searchTerm%' OR
                                      last_name LIKE '%$searchTerm%' OR
                                      date LIKE '%$searchTerm%'";

$results = mysqli_query ($db_connect, $query)
           or die (mysqli_error (db_connect));

if (mysqli_num_rows ($results) >= 1) {
    $record = "";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($results)) {
        include "result.php";
        } echo $record . "<hr />$search_form</main>";
    } else {
        echo "<h1>0 Matching Records</h1><hr />$search_form";
        };
```

Errors:

> Illegal mix of collations for operation 'like'

Comment: `mysqli` is outdated use PDO instead. And dont forget to sanitize your inputs.

Comment: How exactly is it not working? Does it give an error? Or does it return an empty set?

Comment: use `mysql_escape_string() ` for `$searchTerm`

Comment: It dies, like an exit(). No errors, at least none that's shown. And layout breaks off somewhere within that script.

Comment: include your code from `result.php` or do `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to see the error.

Comment: ...Where should I put `error_reporting(E_ALL)`? I tried at the top and at the bottom, no errors returned. Also, `mysql_escape_string($searchTerm)` did not work, if I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: Also in file "php.ini" set "display_errors = On", then restart server.

Comment: Added error_reporting, escape string, and changed php.ini. Not too sure how to work with PDO...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a mess - or you copy/pasted in a hurry with errors.

First your query:

```
$query = " SELECT * FROM members WHERE first_name LIKE '%".mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect, $searchTerm)."%' ";
```

Mind the mysqli_real_escape_string - the minimum sanitize you need.

Then the result:

```
$results = mysqli_query ($db_connect, $query) or die (mysqli_error ($db_connect));
```

You have messed mysqli_ and mysql_ (in die function). Not good.

Now, if these two changes don't help you, try to put at the very top of your script, above everything else:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

This should help you pinpoint any php errors in your code.

Comment: :o Yes, totally missed the mysqli. Gave me `Illegal mix of collations for operation 'like'`. The other gave a whole bunch. And, what is `$server_connect`? `$db_connect`?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Need a fix...

`date LIKE '%$searchTerm%'` isn't working. Breaks the code. So far, I've tried changing `LIKE` to `=`, removing `%` , putting in `mysqli_real_escape_string ($db_connect , $searchTerm)`.

As for database field, it's a date type.

> Illegal mix of collations for operation 'like'